# Zabbix monitoring and power conservation

Tags: zabbix

How can I configure Zabbix to allow hosts to be unreachable at unplanned times?

We have some cluster running where usually not all nodes are completely utilized (VMware, Slurm, OpenStack) and we are currently evaluating where we can shut down hosts do conserve power when possible.

Both VMware and Slurm can do this easily, but they more or less randomly decide which hosts to shut down and when, so maintenance windows are out.

On Slurm I have to write a script to handle the shutdown and power up, I could add an API call there that disables and enables monitoring of the shut down server, but on VMware I can't do this.

The only way I can currently think of are trigger dependencies, but I don't really see how I could configure them in a useful way.

---

Some clarifications:

- I want to "pause" monitoring of nodes that are shut down *intentionally*
- I still need alarms to be triggered when nodes are down *unintentionally*
- I would prefer not to install anything on an ESXi host, except maybe as a VIB that is going to be supported in the foreseeing future
- I would prefer to have everything directly in Zabbix or on the Zabbix host
- I would prefer to have the same method for all types of hosts, so it's easier to maintain

---

My current idea (work in progress):

- Monitoring of the node state via control plane
- A trigger that is triggered when the state is in planned standby
- An action that either enables/disables the host or creates/deletes maintenance periods
  This needs a small script on the Zabbix host that utilizes the API, but this is fine for me

Comment: I can imagine that if you monitor vmware, you should be able to find the on/off status of the vms that are found there. If that is the case they could be added to the items using the vm discovery rule. (I don't do vm so its just guessing)

Comment: The status of VMs is irrelevant. They are migrated to other hosts before a host shuts down. The question is about actual hardware.

Comment: and the hardware had agents on it? Can you run zabbix_sender during such a controlled shutdown?

Comment: No, the hardware does not have an agent running. And even if it had, I don't see how zabbix_sender would be helpful as it can only send monitoring data.

Comment: a flag can be send, no problem. For which hosts do you want to handle the unplanned but on purpose unreachability? The hardware hosts? Since no agents are on them, how do you monitor them now?

Comment: The ESXi hosts are monitored via IPMI and SNMP, as well as ICMP and HTTP

Comment: I'm unclear on what the actual question: Is it "how do I signal Zabbix from ESXi that the host is going down and should not be monitored until further notice?" or is it "how do I execute such a procedure at ESXi shutdown and startup?"  If the former, I can't help much (I only briefly trialed Zabbix a few years ago).  If the latter, you have a very Linux-like CLI environment to work on the host with some familiar init.d style scripts and other utilities to customize startup and shutdown. (ex: service.sh to exec scripts in /etc/init.d, shutdown.sh script,  etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued with my work in progress from the question and want to share the result in case someone else has a similar issue.

First I'm getting the state of the relevant nodes from their specific control plane.

### Slurm

Agent configuration on one of the control nodes:

```
UserParameter=slurm.nodes.discovery,sinfo -N -h -o '{"{#NODENAME}":"%N"}' |jq -sr '[.[]]'
UserParameter=slurm.node.state[*],sinfo -h -o %T -n $1
```

Zabbix discovery rule:

- Key: slurm.nodes.discovery

  - Item prototype

    - Name: `Slurm node {#NODENAME} status`
    - Type: Zabbix agent
    - key: `slurm.node.state[{#NODENAME}]`
    - Type of information: Text
  - Trigger prototype

    - Name: `Slurm node {#NODENAME} in stand by`
    - Operational data: `{#NODENAME}`
    - Severity: Information
    - Expression: `find(/controlnodename/slurm.node.state[{#NODENAME}],#3,"regexp","[~#]$")=1`
    - Tags: `powersave`: `standby`

### VMware vSphere

I've written a small script to get the powerstate of the ESXi hosts from the vCenter API:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from pyVim import connect
from pyVmomi import vim

vc_url = "vcenter.example.com"
vc_user = "zabbix@vsphere.local"
vc_password = "aHR0cDovL2JpdC5seS8xVHFjd243Cg=="

if len(sys.argv) < 1:
print("host parameter missing", file=sys.stderr)
os.exit(3)

esx_name = sys.argv[1]

my_cluster = connect.ConnectNoSSL(vc_url, 443, vc_user, vc_password)

content = my_cluster.RetrieveContent()
object_view = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, [vim.HostSystem], True)

host_list = object_view.view
object_view.Destroy()

for host in host_list:
if host.name == esx_name:
    print(host.runtime.powerState)

connect.Disconnect(my_cluster)
```

This was the only way I could find to get the status of hosts even when they are turned off.

Zabbix discovery rule:

- Key: `vmware.hv.discovery[{$VMWARE.URL}]`
  Type: Simple check

  - Item prototype

    - Name: `Power state of Hypervisor {#HV.NAME}`
    - Type: External check
    - Key: `vsphere_host_powerstate.py[{#HV.NAME}]`
    - Type of information: Text
  - Trigger prototype

    - Name: `VMware Host {#HV.NAME} in stand by`
    - Operational data: `{#HV.NAME}`
    - Severity: Information
    - Expression: `last(/vc/vsphere_host_powerstate.py[{#HV.NAME}])="standBy"`
    - Tags: `powersave`: `standby`

### Common configuration

The field `Operational data` is important, as I use it later when the scripts are called with the macro `{EVENT.OPDATA}`. The tag `powersave` with the value `standby` in triggers is used so I can use a single action for all hosts.

I debated if machines that are shut down for powersaving should be disabled in Zabbix or placed into a maintenance window.

I decided that I find it more intuitive to have the machines in a maintenance window:

- if it is disabled it is not obvious for everybody who is managing the machines in Zabbix **WHY** it is disabled
- The description of the maintenance window is displayed directly in the events

I've written a script to add and remove the machines in maintenence windows:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# set -xv
ZBX_URL="https://zabbix.example.com/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php"
ZBX_USERNAME="zabbix-api"
ZBX_PASSWORD="aHR0cDovL2JpdC5seS8xVHFjd243Cg=="
ZBX_MAINTENANCE_ID=431

function usage {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  $0 <hostname> <maintenance_add|maintenance_remove>"
}

function api_error {
    echo -n "API ERROR: "
    echo "$*" | jq -r .error.data
    exit 3
}

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Error: argument missing"
    usage
    exit 1
fi

function zbx_request {
    REQUEST='{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "'$1'",
        "params": '$2',
        "auth": "'$AUTH'",
        "id": 1
    }'
    # echo "$REQUEST" |jq

    RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' \
    -d "$REQUEST" "$ZBX_URL")

    echo "$RESPONSE" | jq --exit-status .result > /dev/null || api_error "$RESPONSE"
    echo "$RESPONSE"
}

function host_get {
    PARAMS='{
            "filter": {
                "host": [
                    "'$1'"
                ]
            }
        }'
    RESPONSE=$(zbx_request "host.get" "$PARAMS")
    echo "$RESPONSE" | jq -r .result[0].hostid
}

function maintenance_get {
    PARAMS='{
            "maintenanceids": [ '$ZBX_MAINTENANCE_ID' ],
            "selectHosts": [ "hostid" ]
        }'
    RESPONSE=$(zbx_request "maintenance.get" "$PARAMS")
    echo "$RESPONSE" |jq .result[0].hosts | jq -r 'map(.hostid)'
}

function maintenance_add {
    MAINTENANCE_HOSTS=$(maintenance_get)
    HOSTID=$(host_get "$1")

    if jq -e '. | index("'"$HOSTID"'")' <<<"$MAINTENANCE_HOSTS"  > /dev/null; th
en return; fi

    HOSTS=$(jq '. += ["'"$HOSTID"'"]' <<<"$MAINTENANCE_HOSTS")

    PARAMS='{
            "maintenanceid": "'$ZBX_MAINTENANCE_ID'",
            "hostids": '$HOSTS'
        }'
    zbx_request "maintenance.update" "$PARAMS" > /dev/null
}

function maintenance_remove {
    MAINTENANCE_HOSTS=$(maintenance_get)
    HOSTID=$(host_get "$1")

    HOSTINDEX=$(jq '. | index("'"$HOSTID"'")' <<<"$MAINTENANCE_HOSTS")
    if [ "$HOSTINDEX" == "null" ]; then return; fi
    HOSTS=$(jq 'del(.['"$HOSTINDEX"'])' <<<"$MAINTENANCE_HOSTS")
    PARAMS='{
            "maintenanceid": "'$ZBX_MAINTENANCE_ID'",
            "hostids": '$HOSTS'
        }'
    zbx_request "maintenance.update" "$PARAMS" > /dev/null
}

RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' \
-d '
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"user.login","params":
{"user":"'"$ZBX_USERNAME"'","password":"'"$ZBX_PASSWORD"'"},
"id":1,"auth":null}
' "$ZBX_URL")
echo "$RESPONSE" | jq --exit-status .result > /dev/null || api_error "$RESPONSE"
AUTH=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | jq -r .result)

case $2 in
    maintenance_add)
        maintenance_add "$1"
    ;;
    maintenance_remove)
        maintenance_remove "$1"
    ;;
    *)
        echo "invalid state: $2"
        usage
        exit 2
    ;;
esac
```

Script configuration:

- Name: `Run Script zbx-set-host.sh maintenance_add`

  - Type: Script
  - Commands: `/path/to/zbx-set-host.sh {EVENT.OPDATA} maintenance_add`
- Name: `Run Script zbx-set-host.sh maintenance_add`

  - Type: Script
  - Commands: `/path/to/zbx-set-host.sh {EVENT.OPDATA} maintenance_remove`

Trigger action:

- Name: `Disable host in stand by (power saving)`
- Conditions:

  - Value of tag `powersave` equals `standby`
- Operations

  - Operation: `Run script "Run Script zbx-set-host.sh maintenance_add"`
  - Target list: current host
- Recovery operations

  - Operation: `Run script "Run Script zbx-set-host.sh maintenance_remove"`
  - Target list: current host

Answer (score 0):

You can define so named [maintenance period](https://blog.zabbix.com/handy-tips-23-suppressing-problems-with-zabbix-maintenance-periods/19458/) (planned downtime).

> ```
> Navigate to Configuration → Maintenance
> Click on the Create maintenance period button
> Type in the maintenance period name
> Select the maintenance type and the activity time window
> Add a period during which your maintenance will take place
> Select hosts and/or host groups
> Optionally, specify tags to suppress only the matching problems 
> Add the maintenance period
> Wait until the configuration changes are picked up by the Zabbix server
> Navigate to Monitoring → Problems
> Confirm if the problems on the host are suppressed
> ```

You can define the above via [Zabbix API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/en/manual/api/reference/maintenance/create).

Comment: As I already stated in the question, maintenance windows are useless. I don't know which host is shut down and when. I also don't know how long it will be down, the host will be turned on automatically when needed. I also don't have any way to create the maintenance window programatically.

Comment: There is API, you can use it. Check my updated answer

Comment: As I also stated in the question, in VMware I don't have any way to make an API call when a host is shut down or turned on.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, you can create sample scheduled job on Zabbix machine to check if particular host is down and create downtime. But the question is how to distinguish real down (accident) from these "planned" downtimes.